# Configure remote connections without sql server installation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

We have an application called `IpSwitch Whatsup` and it's installed in a machine that I can connect to remotely as administrator. This is all in our intranet.

We need to connect to the sql server database being used by `IpSwitch Whatsup`, but this particular machine doesn't have sql server installed. On the other hand, in `sql server configuration manager` there is indeed a sql server installation for whatsup (the entry says `SQL Server (WHATSUP)`).

So, two questions:

- How does one go about in connecting to this database? I'm pretty sure I know the name of the database and I already know the server name and instance, so I would like to connect to this DB from a sql server installation in another machine.
- How does one configure a sql server installation to receive remote connections if it doesn't have sql server installed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you just type in (or browse) the appropriate instance name and authentication options using SSMS - which is the GUI tool used to manage sql server instances. Note - the term "sql server installation" can mean different things so it is not a useful reference.

As for the second question, review the information [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/walzenbach/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008/). Note that any task you do in SSMS can be done via tsql - you can see the appropriate commands using the script button in the SSMS dialog windows.

And you can also (and probably should based on these questions) install SSMS on the same machine as your server instance so you can do "anything" "anywhere". Now would probably be a good time to review your disaster recovery options (and start backing up your databases regularly).